# How can I wrap text from one text control to another?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, word-wrap

I'm attempting to create a program in C# that would allow dynamic wrapping across rich text box controls.  For example, I begin typing in one available control, as soon as a horizontal scrollbar would appear and the rich text box wraps to the next line, it would instead create a new rich text box control underneath and place my cursor there.  This method would also need to support moving text back and forth between controls in the case of deleting/changing existing text.

Why you ask?  My church requires a program that will allow easily pasting text and it automatically going across as many slides as needed which supports different fonts, sizes, weights, colors, and undo and redo.  All this would need to be done on the fly so the user does not need to use some sort of preview mode to go back and forth to accomplish what they're trying to do.

Comment: I can't think of any good reason for doing this, instead of just using one multiline control. The complexity in your proposed solution would be unmanageable, and it's all already handled for you in one control.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for something like order of service, or words to hymns? The solution for that is to use the scrollbar or the PgDn button. In a Web Browser.

I agree with Chris Ballard. Really, this doesn't look like the right way to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, this is for words, displayed in order, slide by slide.  The reason I ended up with this proposed solution is due to two requirements: 1. Must be able to just paste, not have to paste pieces onto slides.  2. Must be able to preview what each slide will look like while editing.  The first requirement can be done with one control, not sure how the second requirement can be done with one control.